# Import gbxml from REVIT Api

Tags: revit-api, gbxml

I want to create my plugin in revit, where there is the option to import the gbxml file. Within the REVIT API there is an import method, where it takes as arguments the path of the file and the options. My question is how is the format of those options? since within the same documentation I only see that it is a class, but I do not see anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This method is available only in MEP. Though the 'options' argument is not currently used, an object still must be provided (may be a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic)). The method will return False if not succeed. e.g when the input xml file does not contain any result elements.

You can check it [here](http://revitapisearch.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/html/7a6bffbf-b0fe-b047-1008-36d57f495417.htm) too

Answer (score 0):

`gbXML` import into Revit is a bit tricky. A number of limitations and possibilities are explained in the [Revit MEP discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-mep-forum/bd-p/188) thread on [importing back gbXML results](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-mep-forum/gbxml-import-back-results/td-p/4634297).